# How should I interpret "on" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> We are endeavoring to better understand the barriers to safe work
>   environments and **implementation of a safety program on film
>   productions**.

In this example, does "implementation of a safety program on film production" mean:

> implementation of (a safety program on film production)
>
> which means implementation of a program, and this program is safety program about
>   film production

or

> (implementation) of (a safety program) on (film production)
>
> which means implement a program to film production, and this program
>   is a safety program

I read this from an email.

Comment: I would take it to mean the second option you give, but I think this is a pretty badly phrased sentence.

Comment: At first I read it as *we want to create a tv program talking about safety on film productions*. After reading it again though, I think it's poorly worded and actually means *We want to better understand how safety programs are implemented during film productions*.

Comment: Some context would help. Without revealing confidential information, can you tell us more about the email's contents or about its author and their job/responsibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is ungrammatical, because the fragment starting with "implementation ..." is a noun phrase with no corresponding verb. Most likely, the author meant:

> We are endeavoring to better understand the barriers to safe work environments and **to implement** a safety program on film productions.

This is [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) and is equivalent to the following two sentences:

> - We are endeavoring to better understand the barriers to safe work environments.
> - We are endeavoring to implement a safety program on film productions.

Here, the preposition "on" means "about": the safety program is *about* film productions. So, the author is creating a safety program. The safety program deals with the subject of film productions.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous and, therefore, open to interpretation.

My *own* initial interpretation was different from the others already provided. I am providing it here as an alternative interpretation—although I'm not saying it's the *correct* interpretation.

> We are endeavoring to better understand the barriers to safe work environments and ***[the]*** implementation of a safety program on film productions.

This can be made even more clear through rephrasing:

> We are endeavoring to better understand the barriers to two things: (1) safe work environments and (2) the implementation of a safety program on film productions.

---

I interpreted it this way because *implementation* is a noun, not a verb. But, regardless of interpretation, it's clear that the sentence is ambiguous.